# Meaning of auditing in the context of computer programming

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of 'auditing' in programming?

For example: "Audit the code you've performed"

Comment: I would never see it in the sentence you gave. _Audit someone's code_ means to review it, to see if standards are followed. People do not perform code, they write it. Code is executed. But written code can be audited.

Comment: Does your dictionary provide definitions of the verb "to audit?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "audit" in the context of programming (or, more correctly, software engineering) is no different from its normal dictionary definition (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**audit**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/audit)
>   [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Conduct an official financial inspection of (a company or its accounts):
>   "*unlimited companies must also have their accounts audited*"
>
> Conduct a systematic review of:
>   "*a method of auditing obstetric and neonatal care*"

However, you cannot "perform code." You can *audit code* or *audit software*.

Comment: You can perform an audit though - "Perform an audit on this code"